# Laravel php foreach Loop get value by key

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I think im getting this simple thing confused. I just want to get the value of my key 'weeks' and 'days'. I have tried the following:

```
@foreach($years as $key3 => $year)
                <h1>{{$key3}}</h1>
                @foreach($year as $key2 => $months)
                    <p>{{$key2}}</p>
                    @foreach($months as $key1 => $days)
                        <p>{{$days['weeks']}}</p>
                        <p>{{$days->weeks}}</p> //try two//
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

which responds with this error:

```
Illegal string offset 'weeks'
```

this is an example of the array im trying to loop:

```
    array:4 [▼
  2016 => array:12 [▼
    "01" => array:2 [▼
      "weeks" => 5
      "days" => "31"
    ]
```

can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Code smell: You probably should use different names for different keys of different arrays.

Comment: can you explain what you mean?

Comment: See L1, L3 and L5? They all share the same variable name `$key` as the key to your nested `foreach` loops. You should rename them to different names so you don't mix them up. (Normally the inner `$key` will overwrite the outer `$key`, but this is good practice)

Comment: okay, good to know. I thought $key was just the name of the positon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the last foreach,

```
@foreach($years as $key => $year)
   <h1>{{$key}}</h1>
   @foreach($year as $key => $months)
        <p>{{$key}}</p>
        {{ $months['weeks'] }}
        {{ $months['days'] }}
   @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Days isn't an array. But month is containing the keys: weeks and days. 
If you want object notation (->) just cast it to an object by typing (object) before the array.

Comment: Why didn't I need the last foreach?

Comment: @RickiMoore because as your array example shows "01" is a month containing an array. That array contains only 2 keys with a value and not another array. So looping through month will only return the values.